# Downloading a zipfile in binary format using python's ftplib

Tags: python-2.6, zip

I have gone through quite a few questions that have been posted which appear to be related, but not entirely the same issue that I am having:

I am using python's ftplib module along with zipfile to download a zip file from ftp in binary format. However, for some reason, the downloaded zip file appears to be in ascii.

I have ensured that a leading `/` does not exist in the path of the file I am downloading (to match the zip specifications).

```
outFile = zipfile.ZipFile(local_file_path, 'w')
myftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' %i, outFile.write(i))  #i - target file path on ftp server
```

This code fails giving me the following error:

```
st = os.stat(filename)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: //$i
```

I tried adding the 'b' option for binary, but zipfile doesn't seem to like it:

```
outFile = zipfile.ZipFile(local_file_path, 'wb')
```

This raises error:

```
RuntimeError: ZipFile() requires mode "r", "w", or "a"
```

I am using python v2.6.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

According to python doc (http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) seems `retrbinary` takes a callback as second parameter:

```
>>> ftp.retrbinary('RETR README', open('README', 'wb').write)
'226 Transfer complete.'
>>> ftp.quit()
```

Documentation says:

> FTP.retrbinary(command, callback[, maxblocksize[, rest]])
>
> Retrieve a file in *binary* transfer mode. command should be an
>   appropriate RETR command: 'RETR filename'. The **callback** function is
>   **called for each block of data received**, with a single string argument
>   giving the data block. [...]

In your example it should be `outfile.write` (instead of `outfile.write(i)`).

```
>>> ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % i, outFile.write)
```